# How can I filter django queryset again to get unique parameters?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, filter, django-filter

Hi I am trying to receive one last message per user. I have filtered out messages but I am getting many messages for one user. How can I get last message of user.

```
   queryset=MessageModel.objects.filter(
          Q(sUser=self.request.user) | Q(rUser=self.request.user)
          ).order_by('-id')

  return queryset
```

I am getting this list from filtering.

```
[
       {
                "message": "Hi b do you want to buy? 2",
                "sUser": 1,
                "rUser": 15,
                "sent": true,
                "pk": 8,
                "user": {
                    "pk": 15
                }
            },
            {
                "message": "a to c",
                "sUser": 1,
                "rUser": 16,
                "sent": true,
                "pk": 7,
                "user": {
                    "pk": 16
                }
            },
            {
                "message": "No thanks not buying this time",
                "sUser": 15,
                "rUser": 1,
                "sent": false,
                "pk": 6,
                "user": {
                    "pk": 15
                }
            },
            {
                "message": "c to a",
                "sUser": 16,
                "rUser": 1,
                "sent": false,
                "pk": 4,
                "user": {
                    "pk": 16
                }
            },
            {
                "message": "Hi b do you want to buy?",
                "sUser": 1,
                "rUser": 15,
                "sent": true,
                "pk": 1,
                "user": {
                    "pk": 15
                }
            }

        ]
```

I want to get message with pk 8 and 7 only because it is the last message to user 15 and 16 but I am getting all messages for 15 and 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I guess you are going for type like facebook messenger's dashboard. First get the related message of the user

```
 relatedMessage=MessageModel.objects.filter(
          Q(sUser=self.request.user) | Q(rUser=self.request.user)
          ).order_by('-id')
```

Add the first message to a list

```
 convoList.append(relatedMessage.latest('id')) #since first message is unique
```

Then find out the friend from each one so that you can distinct who exactly the friend is (either sender or receiver which may be you or friend, since we are filtering message sender or receiver being you or your friend).

```
  friend = message.sUser
    if message.sUser==self.request.user:
        friend=message.rUser
```

Great! You found which one your friend is.
Now for each message in relatedMessage check if message of you friend exist in your convoList or not. If it does not exist then add it to the convolist. Finally create serializer and return its data or queryset whichever you prefer.

This is preferred because it just makes one query to the database hence creating calculating part in the server. If you had first got related user from database then gone for again filtering message, it would be much costly due to huge query twice in database.

Answer (score 0):

you have to

```
  queryset=MessageModel.objects.filter(
          Q(sUser=self.request.user) | Q(rUser=self.request.user)
          ).order_by('-id')
  if queryset.exists():

      return queryset[0]
  else:
      return None
```

Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the `Q` expressions in your original query match what you asked for, but let's assume you want the most recent received message for every user and that you can depend on the ordering of `id` such that the higher the `id` the more recent.

If you are using a database backend that supports `DISTINCT ON` you can do the following:

```
most_recent_messages = MessageModel.objects.all().order_by('rUser', '-id').distinct('rUser')
```

You can add a `filter` instead of `all` if you want to filter the queryset further to particular users for example.